# MVC, JSP + Servlets - How to put/attach certain object to application scope on application loading?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, model-view-controller, jstl

> MVC - JSP + Servlets, TomEE, MySQL, Eclipse

I know how to put something to application scope in `servlet`, and forward request to some `jsp` page, where I read data from some of `scopes(request, session, aplication)`. But, I would like to have certain object in application scope (Servlet Context) when I load my application. 
In `web.xml` I have specified application entry point:

```
   <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/home.jsp</welcome-file>
   </welcome-file-list>
```

I would like to have some data in application scope, because I am creating menu items from that data.
So, when app starts, no servlet has been processed yet, app goes straight to `home.jsp`, so there is nothing attached to any scope. Or situation when user have bookmarked some of other application jsp pages, and goes straight there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`ServletContextListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html)

> Interface for receiving notification events about ServletContext
>   lifecycle changes.

You implement its `contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent)` method giving you access to the `ServletContext` through the `ServletContextEvent`. You can then add any attribute to it and reference that attribute in the jsp.

Obviously you'll have to register the `ServletContextListener` with the `<listener>` element in your deployment descriptor

```
<listener>
    com.yourcomp.listeners.YourListener
</listener>
```

The container will take care of initializing this class and invoking its `contextInitialized()` method when the web application starts up.

Comment: @Wlad You're welcome. On a related note, if you are using Servlet 3.0, you can also just annotate your class with `@WebListener` instead of registering it with `<listener>`.

Comment: I was using my project with `servlet-api.jar` included from some older Tomcat version. So i was declaring servlets and their mappings in `web.xml`. Now, as you suggested, i would like to declare servlets with annotations. I am using Tomee plus 1.5.2, removed old `servlet-api.jar`, added `servlet-api.jar` from tomee/lib folder to build path, in `web.xml` version is set to 3.0. I have annotated servlet with `@WebServlet("/LoginController")`, and  Eclipse is not showing any errors. But, on deploying i get error: `package javax.servlet.annotation does not exist`

Comment: Doesn't matter. Project clean and rebuilt fixed it.